# External process hangs

Tags: process

I have written a simple Python 3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Hello world!')
```

The script works from the shell:

```
$ ./hello-world 
Hello world!
```

Then, I have written some Lisp to run the script:

```
(defun hello-world-process-sentinel (process event)
  (message "Process: %s; Event: %s" process event))

(defvar hello-world-process (make-process :name "hello world"
                                        :buffer (get-buffer-create "*hello world*")
                                        :command "hello-world"
                                        :sentinel #'hello-world-process-sentinel))
```

`(process-status hello-world-process)` returns `run`, but the `*hello world*` buffer stays empty, and the sentinel doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:command '("hello-world")` instead. Here is the related docstring of `make-process`.

> :command COMMAND -- COMMAND is a list starting with the program file
>   name, followed by strings to give to the program as arguments.